# Get tomcat IP and Port in the servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am running multiple instances of my `Servlet` on 3 different `tomcat` instances with different `ports` and `IP`s, now I want to log which request is coming from which tomcat instance.

Any idea how can I achieve this? Thanks.

### Update

I tried `getServerName()` from `mabac` answer, but it sends the host name not the ip. If I send below curl request:

```
curl -v  \ -H 'Host:example.com' \ 127.0.0.1:1234/
```

then the serverName is `example.com`

Comment: Figure out what the difference between each server is, and put it in a configuration item. It's always better to handle such things explicitly, if you just stick the IP and port in there the next person reading your code will have no idea why you did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the local server name and port name:

```
ServletRequest.getLocalName();  // pc-name
ServletRequest.getLocalAddr(); // 127.0.0.1
ServletRequest.getLocalPort();  // 1234
```

Comment: I prefer this answer, because it is the host and port of the machine running the Servlet, and not the host and port given in the request (what the client is supposed to call). But it depends on the case you are wanting to cover.

Answer (score 1):

```
ServletRequest.getServerName()
ServletRequest.getServerPort()
```

Comment: thanks, but `getServerName()` returns the domain name and not the IP which the instance is running. Suppose if I send this curl request: `curl -v  \
-H 'Host:example.com' \
127.0.0.1:1234/` then the serverName is `example.com`